# File I/O producing gibberish on output

Tags: java, io

I'm learning File I/O using Java.

Following are my codes from two different Java files. One is "File" with the main class, the other is "FileWrite."

I was able to implement string input and output. But the output textfile has gibberish in the beginning and I am not sure why.

[File.Java]

```
package file;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class File {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("B:\\fileIn.txt")))
            {
              String stCurrent;

              while ((stCurrent = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(stCurrent);
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
                    FileWrite fW = new FileWrite();
                    fW.serializeAddress("Boston", "Canada");
        }
}
```

[FileWrite.Java]

```
package file;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class FileWrite {

   public void serializeAddress(String city, String country) {
       try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("B:\\address.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
                obOut.writeUTF(city);
                obOut.writeUTF(country);
        obOut.close();
        System.out.println("Output Done");
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Now, on "obOut.writeUTF(city); obOut.writeUTF(country);" I separated out two string inputs. Is there a way to combine them into one? As in obOut.writeUTF(city, counry) instead of two. Or is this only achievable through making these into an object?

[Update]
Imported a couple more and I tried

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileWriter("B:\\addressPS.txt")); 
ps.println(city); 
ps.println(country); 
ps.close(); 
But with errors, any clue?
```

Comment: The reasons you have "gibberish" is that you are writing Java objects to the stream. Even though the objects you are writing are strings, the ObjectOutputStream has to write all that information to a binary stream (not text) so that you could read those objects back in... as mentioned below, using PrintStream and FileWriter would get  you a text file rather than a binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right thing keeping them separate already.  City and country are different fields.

A very common mistake is not making a distinction between binary and text files/socket streams.  You are a mixing the two which will lead to confusion.  I suggest you only sue text Writer/Reader or binary Input/OuptutStream unless you have a *very* clear idea of what you are doing.

In short if you what to write text use

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileWriter(textFileName));
ps.println(city);
ps.println(country);
ps.close();
```

Comment: Could you tell me which one am I using? Where in the code am I mixing? Also, when you say confusion, meaning it produces jibberish in the text file?

Comment: Also, if I have input.txt file of upto 100,000 entries, what are something I need to make sure the program handles that many entries? (Not sure why my input codes are gone).

Comment: Imported a couple more and I tried PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileWriter("B:\\addressPS.txt"));
                ps.println(city);
                ps.println(country);
                ps.close();   But with errors, any clue?

Comment: You are writing binary to a file with a `.txt` extension which implies it's a text file but it is not so you can't read it as a text file. 100,000 entries is usually fairly small unless you have a mobile device or very large entries e.g. 100KB each.  What you do about the errors depends on what they are.

Answer (score 0):

writeUTF takes strings also, you don't have to create new object for city and county.

Cant you do `obOut.writeUTF(city +" "+country);` ?

Comment: can I use "+" in parameters as an argument? Or does not matter since "+" makes the whole thing into a single string?

Comment: It makes them a single bigger string.

Answer (score 0):

The gibberish is because `.writUTF()` writes data in a modified UTF format which is mentioned in the javadocs.

An `ObjectOutputStream` is generally used to output OBJECTS but I suppose you can use it for strings as well. You can use the respective `.readUTF()` method in the `ObjectInputStream` class in order to read the data in your file back.

---

Also, you have tried to use the try-with-resources block which is new to Java SE7. You should NOT do it the way you have done so. You should do this instead:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("B:\\fileIn.txt"); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);) {

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Splitting the FileReader and the BufferedReader will allow Java SE7 to close both the streams with ease. The way you have done it, only the BufferedReader stream will get closed after the try block finishes.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `ObjectOutputStream` produces 'gibberish'. It's not intended for human consumption, it is a format used to write out objects so that you can read them back. You're not supposed to be able to make sense of the results in a text editor. To make human-readable content, just use an `OutputStreamWriter` or even a `PrintWriter`. In short, your last example is correct, and if you get errors, please edit your question to tell us what the errors are.